# How do I retrieve a specific image from a specific link? (Programming Beginner)

Tags: image, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2, imdb

I'm a programming beginner - so apologies if this question is not appropriate. I have tried my best to search the internet for an answer for the better part of today. 
I'm trying to retrieve the image from this link: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/mediaviewer/rm2809748992

I am using the code below: (I know it fetches all of the images.)

My question is - why does this code work on this link: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/?ref_=nv_sr_5 but not on this link: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/mediaviewer/rm2809748992 ?

```
import urllib2
import os
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/mediaviewer/rm2809748992"
default_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"),"Pictures")
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(URL).read())
imgs = soup.findAll("img",{"alt":True, "src":True})

for img in imgs:
    img_url = img["src"]
    filename = os.path.join(default_dir, img_url.split("/")[-1])
    img_data = opener.open(img_url)
    f = open(filename,"wb")
    f.write(img_data.read())
    f.close()
```

I would like to fetch the image from this link: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/mediaviewer/rm2809748992

I am currently getting no images with the above code from this link. It works with other links though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because the `img` tags inside that url don't have the `alt` attribute, which you are defining for filtering those `img` tags with:

```
imgs = soup.findAll("img",{"alt":True, "src":True})
```

that list returns empty.

Comment: I assume you are checking that in the browser, which could be loading more things into the DOM because of javascript rendering. The direct request to that url (the GET request) doesn't include the tags you are specifying.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for clarifying this. I would still love to figure out how to get that specific image.